# MongoDB insert and find correctly when using PL but records not shown on mongo shell

Tags: mongodb

I'm writing dummy server to insert to mongodb, the connection string already match `mongo` command line connection string, the database and collection name too. Inserting using programming language (PL) driver works fine, Inserting using `mongo` shell also works fine. But both record seems doesn't shown each other (records that inserted using PL only can be seen when queried using PL, records that inserted using `mongo` shell only can be found when queried using `mongo` command line). What's the possible cause for this?

[image: on programming language]
[image: on mongo shell/command line]

On programming language (there's bunch of records already, only showing first 2 records)
[image: on programming language]

On mongo shell (only 1 record which I inserted just now)

```
rs0:PRIMARY> db.stats()
{
        "db" : "test",
        "collections" : 1,
        "views" : 0,
        "objects" : 1,
        "avgObjSize" : 36,
        "dataSize" : 36,
        "storageSize" : 24576,
        "indexes" : 1,
        "indexSize" : 24576,
        "totalSize" : 49152,
        "scaleFactor" : 1,
        "fsUsedSize" : 138781839360,
        "fsTotalSize" : 233197473792,
        "ok" : 1,
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1598360409, 1),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
                }
        },
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1598360409, 1)
}
rs0:PRIMARY> db.test1.points.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f4506c18fda02c740f2650d"), "test" : 1 }
```

What's the possible cause of this? was it because I modify the `systemd` command line argument from
`ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf`
to
`ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf --replSet rs0`

But this on the server, this should globally effecting both client right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, just know that this is **NOT** the correct way to access the database

```
db.dbName.colName
db.test1.points.find()
```

this is the [correct way](https://kb.objectrocket.com/mongo-db/how-to-change-the-mongo-default-database-from-test-204), I don't know since when this changed or it's already like that since beginning..

```
db = db.getSiblingDB('dbName')
db = db.getSiblingDB('test1')
db.points.find()
```